# absolute path source php

Tags: php

This is maybe just a trivial question, but I don't really know what is the best practice to include, says javascript, img, or css using absolute path

What I am really using right now is using the code like this

```
<?php
$prefix = '//';
$rootFolder = $prefix . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
```

so then when i want to include something like jquery, I would just type the code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $rootFolder ?>/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

is this good enough? Or should I modify the prefix to "http://" or maybe there is some better way using another superglobal variable and such?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you need the absolute path?  Why not just use src="/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">

Comment: Are your projects hosted in sub folders? Is that why you need to prefix the path?

Comment: because when I am working with multiple pages nested in folders, I think it's quite troublesome to use a lot of ../../

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered in a correct way, because absolute and relative paths, both have their own importance on a website.

For search engines, they dont like websites with absolute links to the same websites. The modern browsers nowadays already read the relative path with the websites current URL prefixed, unless "/" is used infront of an URL. So, it should not harm when you try to use a relative path as much as possible.

*Another case is*, If you application is extendable by multiple modules. Generally taking, an admin module and one user module. If these module share a common resource folder for JS, CSS and others then its useful and easy to create a relative paths.

Since, your question is concerned about accessing a resource from the root folder, you should be fine as it is i.e using relative paths.

Comment: So what you are saying is the method I am using above is not recommended? is sticking with relative path using ../.. good enough? You know because sometimes in development mode, We often move pages from one folder to another and we have to recode the relative path to the source we needed

Comment: @FelixPerdana, That is a coding inability to make a system crash once you change the folder structure. For a simplest reason, one defination per structure should be enough to everything in that.

Comment: @FelixPerdana, And, No, I prefer using relative path, over absolutes, unless they are for emails.

Comment: sorry but I don't quite get it. So what do we really have to do if we want to change the folder structure freely without worrying about the source pointing to the wrong path? I have googled it but I don't think I get the information I need

Comment: Just define a global path on your bootstrap class like  `define("root_path", "../../")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `src="/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"`, the leading slash will go to the root.  So it doesn't matter which folder level you are in, it will always find it.  This is basically absolute but without the protocol and domain name.

If you are always on the same server, you don't need the host name at all (it's best not to include it if you ever move domain).